# Massive azure wasp JSON folder(450 GB) read in spark optimized way

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have processed file in azure spark . It takes long time to process the file . can anyone please suggest me the optimized way to achieve less process timings . Also attached my sample code with this.

```
// Azure container filesystem, it is contain source, destination, archive and result files
val azureContainerFs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

// Read source file list
val sourceFiles = azureContainerFs.listStatus(new Path("/"+sourcePath +"/"),new PathFilter {
  override def accept(path: Path): Boolean = {
    val name = path.getName
    name.endsWith(".json")
  }
}).toList.par


// Ingestion processing to each file
for (sourceFile <- sourceFiles) {


  // Tokenize file name from path
  val sourceFileName = sourceFile.getPath.toString.substring(sourceFile.getPath.toString.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)

  // Create a customer invoice DF from source json
  val customerInvoiceDf = sqlContext.read.format("json").schema(schemaDf.schema).json("/"+sourcePath +"/"+sourceFileName).cache()
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please write us a bit more about your stack, and processing power (number of masters, slaves, how you deploy code, things like that)

Comment: Master: 4 Core - 28GB RAM
Worker: 4 Node Each 8 Core 58GB RAM
Spark Submit: 21 Executor 1 Core 7GB RAM